# Kingsway Source Entity Names not the same as D365 F&O

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, kingswaysoft

I am using Kingsway to start transforming data, the problem starts when I try to export catalogs from d365 for example "Commission sales group", and it is not in the list of entities that kingsway's AX Source shows.

Does anyone have an idea of how Kingsway chooses or decides the name of the entities, and how is it possible to know which entities I can and cannot access ?[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQNXS.jpg)

know the entities that i can access